# Java audio keeps crackling in custom-made Sound class

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

To keep it short and simple, I am using a custom Sound class for Java, but the way I am using it, it is for some reason, producing a lot of crackling noise for certain sounds. If uploading the audio might be helpful, please let me know.

This is the code of the Sound class that I am using:

```
package brad.classes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;

/*
 * Custom class for playing audio (audio file must be in src)
 */
public class Sound {
    private ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null; //Puts music data into loop
    private InputStream in = null; //Takes in music file as input
    private AudioStream audioStreamMusic = null; //Takes in InputStream of music file as input
    private AudioData audioData = null; //Changes AudioStream to data
    private boolean loopable; //Whether the music input is meant to be looped or not
    private String music; //The name of the music file
    private double length; //The duration of the audio snippet in seconds
    private static boolean isStopped = false;

    /*
     * Takes in music file name and whether or not the file is loopable
     */
    public Sound(String music, boolean loopable) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        if(music.length() < 4 || !music.substring(music.length() - 4, music.length()).equals(".wav"))
            throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must be .wav)");
        else if(new File(music).length() > 1000000)
            throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must not be over 1 megabyte)");
        this.music = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + music;
        this.loopable = loopable;
        in = new FileInputStream(music);
        audioStreamMusic = new AudioStream(in);
        if(loopable) {
            audioData = audioStreamMusic.getData();
            loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audioData);
        }
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(music));
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        long frames = stream.getFrameLength();
        length = (double) frames/format.getFrameRate();
    }

    /*
     * Also takes in whether the file size limit should be ignored
     */
    public Sound(String music, boolean loopable, boolean override) throws IOException {
        if(music.length() < 4 || !music.substring(music.length() - 4, music.length()).equals(".wav"))
            throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must be .wav)");
        if(!override) {
            if(new File(music).length() > 1000000)
                throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must not be over 1 megabyte)");
        }
        this.music = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + music;
        this.loopable = loopable;
        in = new FileInputStream(music);
        audioStreamMusic = new AudioStream(in);
        if(loopable) {
            audioData = audioStreamMusic.getData();
            loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audioData);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Plays audio file
     */
    public void play() {
        if(loopable)
            AudioPlayer.player.start(loop);
        else {
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(music);
                audioStreamMusic = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStreamMusic);
            }
            catch(IOException error) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Stops audio file if playing
     */
    public void stop() {
        if(loopable)
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(loop);
        else
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(audioStreamMusic);
    }

    /*
     * Returns a string representation of the sound, including
     * the given name of the audio file as well as whether or
     * not it is loopable
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Sound[music = %s, loopable = %b]", music, loopable);
    }

    public boolean equals(Sound other) {
        if(music.equals(other.music))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Returns value of music
     */
    public String getMusic() {
        return music;
    }

    /*
     * Returns value of loopable
     */
    public boolean getLoopable() {
        return loopable;
    }

    /*
     * Returns value of length
     */
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /*
     * Plays group of Sounds
     */
    public static Thread playGroup(Sound[] sounds, boolean loopable) throws InterruptedException {
        return playGroup(new ArrayList<Sound>(Arrays.asList(sounds)), loopable);
    }

    /*
     * Plays group of Sounds
     */
    public static Thread playGroup(ArrayList<Sound> sounds, boolean loopable) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    int i = 0;
                    try {
                        sounds.get(0).play();
                        Thread.sleep((long) (sounds.get(0).getLength() * 1000));
                        for(i = 1; i < sounds.size(); ++i) {
                            sounds.get(i).play();
                            sounds.get(i - 1).stop();
                            Thread.sleep((long) (sounds.get(i).getLength() * 1000));
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        sounds.get(i).stop();
                        break;
                    }
                } while(loopable && !isStopped);
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public static void stopGroup(Thread t) {
        while(t != null && !t.isInterrupted()) {
            t.interrupt();
            isStopped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I removed a lot of the code. So, I hope this is somewhat concise enough to get the basic idea.

```
package defense;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import brad.classes.Sound;

public class Runner extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static char dir = 'u';

    static int delay = 10;
    static int angle = 0;
    static int breakCount = 0;
    static int breakFrame = 0;
    static int count = 0;
    static int gifCount = 0;
    static int currentDirection = 0;
    static int gameOverCount = 0;
    static int gameOverFrame = 0;

    static boolean isHard = true;
    static boolean runsGif = false;
    static boolean heartDone = false;
    static boolean gameOverDone = false;
    static boolean firstEnd = true;
    static boolean secondEnd = true;

    protected Timer timer;

    BufferedImage gif;
    BufferedImage heart;
    BufferedImage heartBreak;
    BufferedImage gameOver;

    static Thread mainSound;

    Attack a1 = new Attack(new LinkedList<Arrow>(), 2);
    Player p = new Player();

    public Runner(String s) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(s);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Runner bp = new Runner();
        frame.add(bp);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocation(dim.width/2 - frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2 - frame.getSize().height/2);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, InterruptedException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Runner a = new Runner("Game");
        ArrayList<Sound> mainTheme = new ArrayList<Sound>();
        int max;
        String base;
        if(isHard) {
            max = 16;
            base = "BATH";
        }
        else {
            max = 12;
            base = "SOJ";
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= max; ++i) {
            mainTheme.add(new Sound("audio/" + base + i + ".wav", false));
        }
        mainSound = Sound.playGroup(mainTheme, true);
    }

    public Runner() {
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(p.getHealth() != 0) {
            drawBG(g);
            drawSqu(g);
            drawCircle(g);
            drawHeart(g);
            p.shield(g, dir);
            gif(g);
            try {
                a1.spawnArrows(g, p);
                p.drawHealth(g);
            }
            catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            drawBG(g);
            if(firstEnd) {
                Sound.stopGroup(mainSound);
                firstEnd = false;
            }
            if(!heartDone)
                breakHeart(g);
            else if(secondEnd){
                secondEnd = false;
                ArrayList<Sound> determination = new ArrayList<Sound>();
                try {
                    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
                        determination.add(new Sound("audio/DT" + i + ".wav", false));
                    }
                    Sound.playGroup(determination, true);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(!gameOverDone){
                gameOver(g);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean breakHeartException(int breakFrame) {
        int[] exceptions = {2, 6, 8, 12, 14, 18, 20, 22, 23};
        for(int exception : exceptions) {
            if(breakFrame == exception)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void makeBreakHeart(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        int width = heartBreak.getWidth();
        int height = heartBreak.getHeight();
        g2d.drawImage(heartBreak, getWidth() / 2 - (width / 2) + 11, getHeight() / 2 - height / 2 + 78, null);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void breakHeart(Graphics g) {
        ++breakCount;
        boolean exception = breakHeartException(breakFrame);
        try {
            heartBreak = ImageIO.read(new File("images/gif/heartBreak" + breakFrame + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(breakCount % 4 == 0 && breakCount != 0 && !exception) {
            ++breakFrame;
            if(breakFrame == 25) {
                try {
                    Sound split = new Sound("audio/split.wav", false);
                    split.play();
                } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(breakFrame == 48)
                heartDone = true;
            breakCount = 0;
        }
        else if(exception) {
            switch(breakFrame) {
                case 2:
                case 12:
                    if(breakCount % 24 == 0) {
                        ++breakFrame;
                        breakCount = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case 14:
                    if(breakCount % 28 == 0) {
                        ++breakFrame;
                        breakCount = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if(breakCount % 8 == 0) {
                        ++breakFrame;
                        if(breakFrame == 9) {
                            try {
                                Sound broke = new Sound("audio/heartBreak.wav", false);
                                broke.play();
                            } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        breakCount = 0;
                    }
            }
        }
        makeBreakHeart(g);
    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        ++gameOverCount;
        try {
            gameOver = ImageIO.read(new File("images/gif/gameOver" + gameOverFrame + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(gameOverCount % 4 == 0 && gameOverCount != 0) {
            ++gameOverFrame;
            switch(gameOverFrame) {
                case 68:
                case 70:
                case 73:
                case 75:
                case 76:
                case 78:
                case 80:
                case 81:
                case 85:
                case 86:
                case 88:
                case 93:
                case 95:
                case 96:
                case 98:
                    try {
                        Sound asgore = new Sound("audio/asgore.wav", false);
                        asgore.play();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if(gameOverFrame == 225)
                gameOverDone = true;
            gameOverCount = 0;
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        int width = gameOver.getWidth();
        int height = gameOver.getHeight();
        g2d.drawImage(gameOver, getWidth() / 2 - (width / 2) + 1, getHeight() / 2 - height / 2, null);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            dir = 'u';
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            dir = 'd';
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            dir = 'r';
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            dir = 'l';
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any further details are needed. Thanks!

**Update 1:**

I just realized that I left out some fairly important information. The playGroup() sounds seem to work fine (or at least good enough) for my purposes. The main problem happens with playing small sound effects over those sounds at the same time.

So, the Sounds that are being put into an ArrayList and put into the playGroup() and stopGroup() methods seem to be working well enough. The main problems occur when I create an individual sound and play it over the main looping sound.

Comment: There is a lot of code to comb through and I doubt all of it is relevant to your question. Please edit your question to be a [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Crackling sound has almost every time something to do with multi-threading.
I coded a working audio library. Use it: https://github.com/RalleYTN/SimpleAudio